# how do i redirect to index page when user enters unwanted action at end of url using zend?

Tags: zend-framework

I am new to zend, I have an action, like **http://test.zend.com/auth/index** which means auth is controller and index is an Action.Now If user enter like **test.zend.com/auth/indexxxx** ,will get redirect to ErrorController page.*I dont want to display Error Controller page here, instead I always want to redirect to index page when user enters unwanted action.*

Kindly help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your error controller redirect to index:

```
$this->_redirect('/index');
```

Comment: You can write an action helper to do so. but redirection is more easer. ;)

Comment: I think that is better to use _forward() rather than _redirect(), this way is much more efficient because the whole system isn't loaded again. If you don't  really need to redirect then use _forward()